# A 99.99 numeric from flat file doesn't want to go in a NUMERIC(4,2)'SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a csv file :

```
1|1.25
2|23.56
3|58.99
```

I want to put this value in a SQL Server table with SSIS.
I have created my table :

```
CREATE TABLE myTable( ID int, Value numeric(4,2));
```

My problem is that I have to create a Derived Column Transformation to specify my cast :

```
(DT_NUMERIC,4,2)(REPLACE(Value,".",","))
```

Otherwise, SSIS don't seem to be able to put my Value in my column, and fill my column with null value.

And I think it is tooooo ugly to do it this way. I want my Derived Column Transformation be here for real new derived column, and not some simple cast that I think SSIS have to detect.

So, what is the standard way to use SSIS to resolve this problem ?

Comment: FWIW, I think you already have the best workaround. Your machine's regional settings use comma and the file uses period - so the file's values have to be changed to match the region setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading this up in international format (56,99 in lieu of 56.99). You need to load this as 56.99 for SQL Server to recognize it as such. Take out the `REPLACE(Value, ".", ",")` and just have the code be:

`(DT_NUMERIC,4,2)(Value)`

Handle the formatting on the application side, not on the data side. The comma is a reserved operator in SQL Server and you can't change that fact.

Comment: You need a data viewer on the Data Flow task, then, to see what is going in and out of the Derived Column task...

Answer (score 1):

```
BULK
INSERT myTable
FROM 'c:\csvtest1.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

**csvtest1.txt**

```
1|1.25
2|23.56
3|58.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used SSIS a whole lot, but can't you set the regional settings on the File Source or at least set the decimal separator?

Answer (score -1):

Can you change your SSIS source column to be in the correct datatype?

Comment: I have tried to define my source column in the correct datatype, but then, all is green, but my column is null everywhere. So I define in string(50) instead, create a new derived column, my cast, and it runs.

Comment: The fact that you are doing a replace of . with , suggests your machine has European or similar settings, and so requires the data to be in 56,78 format rather than 56.78.  If you can change the regional settings then it will work, otherwise you will have to do it this way.  Doing this is not bad practice either, SSIS forces a lot of derived columns for simple actions.

Comment: I will not change my regional settings. Come on I'm in France ;) But if you don't think it's too ugly, I can change my mind on that. It's simpler ^^

Comment: I'd go with your solution, it works and it won't slow you down.  It should also work if your source suddenly changes to be in European format.

Comment: SQL Server does not allow you to change the number format. The comma is a (very) reserved operator and it will not budge on that fact. You have to use the English notation for decimals in the data side, and can convert it on the application layer.

Answer (score -1):

**If you have control over the production of your file**, I'd suggest you to format values without ANY decimal or thousand separation : in this case I'ld have a file with values:

```
1|125  
2|2356  
3|5899
```

and then apply a division by 100 when importing the data. While it has the advantage of being culture-independent, of course it has some drawbacks:
1) First of all, it may not be possible to impose this format of the file.
2) It presumes that all numeric values are formatted accordingly, in this case every value is multiplied by 100; this can be an issue if you have to mix values from countries with different decimal positions (many have two decimals, but some have zero decimals).
3) It may severely impact with other routines, maybe out of your control
Therefore, this can really be an option if you have total control on the csv file.